How to test whether a 2-particle Hamiltonian is rotationally invariant?
I am learning quantum mechanics, and am currently covering rotational invariance and angular momentum.
In the material I am going over, we are given the Hamiltonian for a system consisting of two particles with spin:
$$\hat{H} = \omega_0 (\hat{S}_{z_1} - \hat{S}_{z_2})$$
where $\omega_0$ is a frequency, and $\hat{S}_{z_i}$ is the spin operator along the z-axis for particle $i$.
My question is, how do I test whether this Hamiltonian is rotationally invariant or not? Especially given this is a two particle system?
A couple of follow up questions that seem related:
1.) Does the Hamiltonian have to commute with $\hat{S} = \hat{S}_1 + \hat{S}_2$ for the Hamiltonian to be rotationally invariant?
2.) Does the Hamiltonian have to commute with $S^2 = \hat{S} \cdot \hat{S}$ in order for it to be rotationally invariant?
3.) What is the intuition of a rotationally invariant Hamiltonian?
Perhaps I am completely off in asking these.
Thank you so much for your help and insight on this!

Rotational invariance means the hamiltonian is invariant under all rotations, so it commutes with all generators of such. If you only had one particle, so if you extinguished the second one, $\hat{H} = \omega_0 \hat{S}_{z} $, this wouldn't be fully rotationally invariant, since
$\hat{S}_{z} $ fails to commute with $\hat{S}_{x} $ and  $\hat{S}_{y} $.
As you ask in 1.), rotational invariance means commutation with all three components of $\hat{\mathbf S} = \hat{\mathbf  S}_1 + \hat{\mathbf  S}_2$, which then further ensures commutation with the quadratic Casimir in your 2.): prove it. So there is nothing more to check.
The intuition 3.) is that a rotation is like two synchronized swimmers, 1 and 2, moving identically under the action of the three $\hat{\mathbf S}$ components. (Mathematicians call this the coproduct on the tensor space of 1 and 2, but don't worry. All you need to know is operators with a subscript 1 commute with all with subscript 2.)
It is then evident that, as in the case of one particle, your hamiltonian  $\hat{H} = \omega_0 (\hat{S}_{z_1} - \hat{S}_{z_2})$ fails to commute with $\hat{S}_{x} $ and  $\hat{S}_{y} $. It commutes with $\hat{S}_{z} $, allowing for a residual axial symmetry.

The Hamiltonian is invariant iff $\omega_{0}=0$.

To determine whether a Hamiltonian possesses a given symmetry, you determine how the symmetries act on the Hilbert space (i.e. the wave functions) and then check if the actions commute with the Hamiltonian, or that the symmetry operations preserve eigenspaces (map eigenvectors to other eigenvectors with the same eigenvalues.)
In the case of rotational symmetry for a system comprised of two distinguishable particles, the Hilbert space is given by $\mathcal H_1\otimes \mathcal H_2$, where $\mathcal H_i$ is the Hilbert space for each particle and $\otimes$ is the tensor product (i.e. wave functions have the form $\psi(x_1,x_2)$, where $x_1$ is a complete measurement of system 1 and $x_2$ is a complete measurement of system 2, and the joint Hilbert space $\mathcal H = \mathcal H_1\otimes \mathcal H_2$ is spanned by product wave functions of the form $\psi_1(x_1)\psi_2(x_2)$.)  Rotational symmetry is a global symmetry, and so it acts on both coordinates simultaneously: in spatial coordinates, $R\circ\psi(x_1,x_2) = \psi(R^{-1}x_1, R^{-1}x_2)$, where $R$ is, for simplicity, a rotation about the origin represented as a matrix.  By expanding both $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ and $\psi(R^{-1}x_1, R^{-1}x_2)$ in an orthonormal basis of elementary harmonics (e.g. products of spherical harmonics, or Gaussian wave packets, or plane waves) you can determine a matrix form for the linear transformation induced by the rotation. For example, if $Y_\alpha(x_1)$ are harmonics for $\mathcal H_1$ and $U_\beta(x_2)$ are harmonics for $\mathcal H_1$, then $\mathcal H = \mathcal H_1\otimes \mathcal H_2$ is spanned by products of the form $Y_\alpha U_\beta$, and we can write $\psi(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{\alpha,\beta} c_{\alpha,\beta} Y_\alpha U_\beta$ for appropriate coefficients $c_{\alpha,\beta}$.  Similarly, $\psi(R^{-1}x_1, R^{-1}x_2)$ can be expanded with coefficients $c_{\alpha,\beta}'$, and because the transformation is linear (i.e. $R\circ (\psi + \phi) = \psi(R^{-1}x) + \phi(R^{-1}x) = R\circ\psi + R\circ \phi$), you are guaranteed that there is a "matrix" $\rho(R)_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta}$ such that $c'_{\alpha\beta} = \sum_{\gamma\delta}\rho(R)_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta}c_{\gamma\delta}$.  Moreover, it turns out that the matrix $\rho(R)_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta}$ "factorizes": there exist smaller matrices $\rho^{(1)}(R)_{\alpha,\gamma}$ and $\rho^{(2)}(R)_{\beta,\delta}$ such that $\rho(R)_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta} = \rho^{(1)}(R)_{\alpha,\gamma}\rho^{(2)}(R)_{\beta,\delta}$.  Moreover, these matrices $\rho^{(1)}(R)$ and $\rho^{(2)}(R)$ are just the rotation matrices for $\mathcal H_1$ and $\mathcal H_2$ respectively (in the $Y_\alpha$ and $U_\beta$ bases.)  This property of rotation operators (and global symmetry operators more generally) generalizes to wave functions that lack "coordinate" degrees of freedom where you can express a symmetry transformation in terms of a mapping of the coordinates.  For example, a transformation rule such as $R\circ \psi_\sigma = \psi_{R^{-1}\sigma}$ would normally be somewhat uninformative for determining the transformation of wave functions with spin degrees of freedom (although for the sake of answering your question you might find this perspective helpful): it is the explicit "matrix" form of the transformation that tells you that rotations act on spin components through (2 by 2) matrices.  In order for a set of matrices to implement rotations consistently, they need to satisfy a few conditions (not just any matrix will do): if $\rho(R)_{ij}$ is the matrix "representation" of a (physical) rotation $R$, then $\rho(R_1R_2)_{ij}$ must equal $\sum_{\ell}\rho(R_1)_{i\ell}\rho(R_2)_{\ell j}$ (i.e. composition of [physical] rotations must be "modeled" consistently by multiplication of [abstract] matrices.)
In the case of spin-$1/2$ particles, these matrices are well-known, and related to the Pauli spin matrices $\hat \sigma_x$, $\hat \sigma_y$, $\hat \sigma_z$ that satisfy/realize the quaternion algebra (i.e. $\sigma_i^2 = \sigma_x\sigma_y\sigma_z = -1$.)
Once you have determined how your system transforms under symmetry operations (e.g. rotations, in your case), you can check if the Hamiltonian gives "consistent" results for wave functions that differ by the symmetry: one way of formulating this in mathematical is to ask if the expectation value of the Hamiltonian, $\langle R\circ \psi| H|R\circ\psi\rangle$, is independent of the rotation $R$ applied to $\psi$ for all wave functions $\psi$, or equivalently, if $\langle \psi|\rho(R)^{\dagger} H \rho(R)|\psi\rangle$ is independent of $R$ for all $|\psi\rangle$, or equivalently*, if $\rho(R)^{\dagger} H \rho(R) = H$ for all $R\in SO(3)$.
It's by taking the derivative of the above constraint ($\rho(R)^\dagger H\rho(R)=H$) near the identity (i.e. at $R=\mathbb I$) that you obtain the symmetry criterion in terms of a commutator. If $R=\mathbb I + \eta + \mathcal O(\eta^2)$ is a rotation matrix near the identity, then $R^TR = \mathbb I$ implies $\eta = -\eta^T$, and so the "tangent space" near the identity consists of antisymmetric 3 by 3 matrices: you can check that this is spanned by three basis vectors, corresponding to the three off-diagonal upper triangular components of the matrix (the three lower-triangular components must be opposite these in sign.)  Let's call the basis vectors $g_i$ (for 'generator'), so $\eta = \sum_i \epsilon_i g_i$ for (small) coefficients $\epsilon_i$.  It turns out that $\rho$ is a linear map too (of matrices), so $\rho(\mathbb I + \eta) = \mathbb I' + \sum_i\epsilon_i\rho(g_i)$, and if $\rho$ factorizes as $\rho_{\alpha,\gamma}\rho_{\beta,\delta}$ then we must also have
\begin{align*}
\delta_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta} + \sum_i \epsilon_i \rho_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta}(g_i) +\mathcal O(\epsilon^2) &= \Big(\delta_{\alpha,\gamma} + \sum_i\epsilon_i\rho^{(1)}_{\alpha,\gamma}(g_i)\Big)\Big(\delta_{\beta,\delta} + \sum_i\epsilon_i\rho^{(2)}_{\beta,\delta}(g_i)\Big) + \mathcal O(\epsilon^2)\\
&=\delta_{\alpha,\gamma}\delta_{\beta,\delta} + \Big(\sum_i\epsilon_i\rho^{(1)}_{\alpha,\gamma}(g_i)\Big)\delta_{\beta,\delta} + \delta_{\alpha,\gamma}\Big(\sum_i\epsilon_i\rho^{(2)}_{\beta,\delta}(g_i)\Big) + \mathcal O(\epsilon^2)
\end{align*}
Since this equation holds for all 'small' $\epsilon_i$ (in particular for $\epsilon_i$ where all components but one vanish), and because $\delta_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta} = \delta_{\alpha,\gamma}\delta_{\beta,\delta}$,
\begin{align*}
\rho_{\alpha\beta,\gamma\delta}(g_i) = \rho^{(1)}_{\alpha,\gamma}(g_i)\delta_{\beta,\delta} + \delta_{\alpha,\gamma}\rho^{(2)}_{\beta,\delta}(g_i)
\end{align*}
or, in slightly condensed notation, $\hat \rho_{total}(g_i) = \hat \rho_1(g_i) + \hat \rho_2(g_i)$, and this result generalizes (by induction say) to systems   consisting of arbitrary numbers of subsystems: $\hat \rho_{total}(g_i) = \sum_\ell \hat \rho_\ell(g_i)$, where it is understood that $\hat\rho_\ell$ acts only on the $\ell$-th subsystem.  For example, if $\mathcal H_1$ and $\mathcal H_2$ both describe (distinguishable) spin 1/2 particles, then $\hat s_{total} = \hat s_1 + \hat s_2$ where $\hat s_1$ and $\hat s_2$ are both represented by Pauli spin matrices, but acting on separate parts/indices of Hilbert space: $\hat s_1:= \hbar\hat \sigma_{\alpha,\gamma}\delta_{\beta,\delta}$, $\hat s_2:=\hbar \hat \sigma_{\beta,\delta}\delta_{\alpha,\gamma}$.
To be continued...
